# Incorporate TWO PHP's - Kimonlabs

Tags: javascript, php, html

Kimonlabs JSON Code

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXX");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
//var_dump($parsed_json->results->collection1);

foreach($parsed_json->results->collection1 as $collection){
echo $collection->title->text . ''; echo $collection->title->href . ''; echo $collection->posted . '';
}
```

PHP Redirect Code

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
```

I'd like to replace

```
http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html
```

with

```
$collection->title->href
```

But I've no idea how to merge the two.

Comment: A basic understanding of PHP syntax would tell you exactly what you need to do: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, my integration with the above codes constantly outputs errors. Obviously, I've tried endlessly, hence why I'm seeking support. Regards.

Comment: If you get an error, then you should tell us what it is. I'm guessing "headers already sent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a foreach() is used, I doubt you can do that... If there are multiple results, your code is going to try to redirect multiple times to a different url (or at least the first it encounters).

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXX");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
//var_dump($parsed_json->results->collection1);

foreach($parsed_json->results->collection1 as $collection){
    header('Location: ' . $collection->title->href);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Ah damn! D'you know any other way to parse Kimonolabs' API using PHP?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve and how the result from http://www.kimonolabs.com/api/e45oypq8?apikey=XXX looks like...

Comment: There are multiple results in this example (property1, property2, and so on)... If you use `header('Location: ...');` the visitor gets redirected immediately... So in this case to the href of property1. You dont do anything with property2... Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But the code in PHP, obviously.

Comment: YES! You're an absolute hero. Thank youuu!